# Encode the input to exclude a given character (part 1)

Tags: code-golf, open-ended-function

Your task is to write 2 functions/programs. They may share code.

The first function must, given a string and a character, output a new string that does not contain that character.

The second function must, given the string from the previous function and the excluded character, reconstruct the original string.

All input strings will be ASCII printable, all output strings must be ASCII printable. You may choose to include or exclude whitespace, if you exclude whitespace it must be excluded from both the input and the output.

#### Examples

One could try to use replace the character with an escape sequence. For example `\#bcda` with excluded character becomes `\\#bcd\#` then you'd know to replace `\#` with whatever character is excluded. However, the excluded character might itself be `#`  or `\` so if one uses this method they'd need to be able to dynamically switch to a different escape sequence in that case.

There is no length limit for the censored string so you could try to encode the entire string in unary, but be careful that the unary char you choose may not be the excluded char.

This is code golf, shortest answer in each language wins. Brownie points for interesting solutions even if they are not the shortest though.

Comment: "You may choose to include or exclude whitespace." It might be worth clarifying that the same choice needs to be made for the input and output--feels like it should be obvious that it would subvert the challenge otherwise, but [a solution that *looks* like it unconditionally uses spaces as delimiters](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266522/85334) seems to have inspired [a solution that actually unconditionally uses spaces as delimiters](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266542/85334).

Comment: Is it possible for input strings to be empty?

Comment: Are we allowed to use different representations of a string for input and output? For example, my Python answer currently does bytes -> str -> list of ints.

Comment: It could be interesting challenge if the second function does not receive the character as input.

Comment: @tsh that will be part 2

Answer (score 11):

## JavaScript (ES6), 59 bytes

#### Encoder (30 bytes)

Expects `(string)(char)`.

```javascript
s=>c=>btoa(s).split(c).join`#`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fcu9DsIgEADgvU9x1gGIShfj0tDBycnFFyil0NCcvYbDv6dHXb/km@3TsktxzYeFRl@aBlbCT4iIECjB9Yd65mrIZMEAg@ng/AjBJx0S3SXDDoRQOtMtp7hMUgyW/ekoVFtVwRQ2nTPdf0tWmleMWTqlZ4pLv@2Lo4UJvUaaZJD1xSPSHl6UcNzUStbvWqm2fAE)

#### Decoder (29 bytes)

Expects `(encoded_string)(char)`.

```javascript
s=>c=>atob(s.replace(/#/g,c))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcuxDoIwFEDRna94gaFtxHYxxsSUwQVZTAyJe6ktAQuP9CHRr0dcb87tzWLIxm6a9yM@3aoUTBi@vgsBPEa4bVH2lJgZG9BAoAu4vL13UfqIAyfYAWM5sMaQOx6YkDPWc@zGlotzkni9ki6sLv4/JxndFIx1XGWqza0Qq8WRMDgZsOWep3X5oKY8UXV9LnbIXtVd61Tw9JNu9gc)

#### Explanation

The encoder turns the input string `s` into a base-64 string, which may only contain `[a-z]`, `[A-Z]`, `[0-9]`, `+`, `/` and `=`. Then it replaces all occurrences of the forbidden character `c` with `#`. If `c` is not a base-64 character, this 2nd step has no effect at all. (In particular, note that the base-64 string can't possibly contain any `#`.)

The decoder does the exact opposite: it replaces all occurrences of `#` with the forbidden character and decodes this as a base-64 string.

Comment: What if the char is `#`?

Comment: @mousetail Then it won't appear in the base-64 string and nothing will be replaced.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 + 5 = 9 bytes

(4 + 4 = 8 bytes if we do not need to handle the empty string*, remove `€`.)

Uses the same approach as others, port of [bsoelch's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266522/53748).

#### [Encoder](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9qZWxsef//T@G5vuG5o0v/w6fhuKJ9//8iMjAxIGFuZCAzMDEsNDAxIv8iMCI)

A dyadic Link that accepts the plaintext on the left and the character on the right and yields the ciphertext.

```
OṾṣK - Link: plaintext, P; character, C  e.g. P="20 cats"; C='0'
O    - cast P to ordinals                      [50,48,32,99,97,116,115]
 Ṿ   - unevaluate                               "50,48,32,99,97,116,115"
  ṣ  - split at occurrences of C             ["5",",48,32,99,97,116,115"]
   K - join with spaces                         "5 ,48,32,99,97,116,115"

                     (note that if C=' ' we get "50,48,32,99,97,116,115")
```

#### [Decoder](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjk1ZYQ939zxqWvP/8PKHOxbV/v@vZKqgY2KhY2KpY2ykY2muY2iooGOooADimRpCZUxMdEyNIGyl/0oGSgA)

A dyadic Link that accepts the ciphertext on the left and the character on the right and yields the plaintext.

```
ḲjVỌ€ - Link: cyphertext X; character C  e.g. X="5 ,48,32,99,97,116,115", C='0'
Ḳ     - split X at spaces                    ["5",",48,32,99,97,116,115"]
 j    - join with C                             "50,48,32,99,97,116,115"
  V   - evaluate as Jelly code                  [50,48,32,99,97,116,115]
   Ọ€ - cast each to a character                "20 cats"
```

* An empty ciphertext evaluates (`V`) to the integer zero, so without `€` the cast (`Ọ`) will convert that to a NULL byte terminated empty string (in all other cases it will vectorise automatically but `€` will implicitly cast this edge-case zero to an empty range first).

Comment: This seems to return an inconsistent output format. Outputting as a list of character codes is fine but `[[], [], [], [98]]` does not seem like a reasonable way to represent a list of character literals to me

Comment: Or if you intend it to be read as a string instead then it fails if the excluded character is `]` or `[` or `,`

Comment: Those TIO links don't work for me

Comment: I don't think your output can be considered a reasonable representation of a string, since you explicitly use out of band info to encode information. A flat array of integers would be fine but `[[65, 32, 108, 105, 115, 116, 32, 105, 115, 32, 102, 105, 110, 101, 58, 32], []]` seems cheaty to me.

Comment: Oh, yeah - output might contain the removed char... deleting!

Comment: @mousetail total rewrite.

Answer (score 4):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 59 bytes

```ruby
f=->s,c{"#{s.bytes}".tr c,?.}
g=->s,c{(eval s.tr ?.,c).pack"U*"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P81W165YJ7laSbm6WC@psiS1uFZJr6RIIVnHXq@WKx0qq5FalpijUAySsNfTSdbUK0hMzlYK1VKq/V9hmxatZGhkbJJYnJKmpGNvFMtVoFABxOnRFToKQO5/AA)

TIO says 64 byes, because 2 function headers and a newline are included.

Inspired by Arnauld's JS answer.

#### Encode

First convert the string to a sequence of 8-bit values, then convert it to a string again, and finally replace the character to be excluded with a dot. The first step is equivalent to `unpack` using UTF-8 byte values, only slightly shorter.

#### Decode

Reverse order: first replace the character that was excluded, then convert it to an array of 8-bit values, and finally pack it to a string. This is equivalent to mapping the `&:chr` method on the list, and then joining the characters, only slightly shorter.

Comment: `eval(s.tr ?.,c).pack"U*"` gives -1

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>7</s> 6 + 5 = 11 bytes

Encoder:

-1 thanks to @KevinCruijssen

```
≠sÇ₁β×
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m73MwDQxyTB1wYKlpSVpuhZrH3UuKD7c_qip8dymw9OXFCclF0NlFiwx4IpRhrAB)

Decoder:

```
g₁вçJ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=7dyxEUNgAIDRYdS5o8idGTJDGnIYgAzAGpq_IE5rBQuolSZRMEOq98pviK__xc8sT4oQxm9TPtK5Orp2W9bpNdT5p75r2N9RAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD80zULPwE)

`J` could be removed for -1 to output a list of characters instead of a string.

Uses unary, with `0` if the character is `1` and `1` otherwise.

Comment: `иJ` can be `×` for -1 byte. Although outputting as a list of characters when a string is being asked is allowed by default, so the `J` in the second program could be removed.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 86 bytes

*inspired by [Arnauld's JavaScript solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/266518/encode-the-input-to-exclude-a-given-character-part-1/266523#266523)*

*-25 bytes, thanks to  corvus_192*

Encoder:

```python
lambda s,c:str([*map(ord,s)]).replace(c,"#")
```

Decoder:

```python
lambda s,c:map(chr,eval(s.replace("#",c)))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fdI7DgIhEAbg2HoKgg0Y3Ox2xsTeA5hYGAsEjJhx2QBqvIiNjY3eSU8juz7R1WS6-fgnk2F_KrZ-bvLD4bjys073PFZ94Mup5Mgx0XPeknF7yQtirGSOTmhiVQFcKCIYbmHalO-8hGJumVpzIO5JA2SCUnobcWnsCqtzTzBOFkbnJICBAjCY4QwH1ozb8gPE6lMHm2VpWlbg6a-82MSwJnKonA-U_4p79WNUE1VtgkbGggwv0N-F31lsa4I3GgBpj2ZcA66OU5_87e74dp7HT7gC)

encodes string as an array sequence of character-codes

---

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 182 bytes

```python
def q(S,N,K,n,d):
 k=sum((ord(c)&K)*N**i for i,c in enumerate(S));s=[]
 while k:s+=[chr(k%n+d)];k//=n
 return s
e=lambda s,c:q(s,128,-1,2,48+2*(c in"01"))
d=lambda s,c:q(s,2,1,128,0)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ddGxTsMwEAbg3U9hWQKdkyuNI4YoVXakSl3KVnUIsaOYJE5rO0I8C0sXeATehZUnIYEilIhKt92n_-50L2-HZ1915nR67X25SD7epSrpEba4wTUalDwltM5c3wJ0VkLBr9c82ASBpmVnqcaCakOV6Vtlc69gy_nKZbs9oU-VbhStUxdmu6KyUF-ZUPL9ql4uM0OoVb63hjqisiZvH2ROHRbpERyKOMGFwBhvkzAOYBzAIsE4J3JOYxTfPOLn7T8PVhsPjN08dtqAAnanmqZjyMYATqZtOQNTNdeDFSKKxhp4dClvaqbwn8h75fxA80txf_0z-rn0919f)

The encoder (`e(s,c)`) interprets the string as a base 128 number and converts it to binary (using `2` and `3` if the excluded character is `0` or `1`).

The decoder (`d(s,c)`) converts a binary number to base 128

Comment: Seems to have the same issue as Arnould's solution that if the excluded character is # it will fail

Comment: @mousetail as far as I can tell it does work, do you have a test-case where it fails?

Comment: My bad, I understand how this works now

Comment: -25 bytes: `e=lambda s,c:str([*map(ord,s)]).replace(c,"#");    d=lambda s,c:map(chr,eval(s.replace("#",c)))`

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `Ss`, 5 + 4 = 9 bytes

```
C?¬S*
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyJTcyIsIiIsIkM/wqxTKiIsIiIsIltdXG4xIl0=)

Input list of characters and then normal input. Outputs a string

```
⌈@ꜝC
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyJTcyIsIiIsIuKMiEDqnJ1DIiwiIiwiXCJcIiJd)

Input the string from the encoder.

Comment: @emanresuA [it can handle 0s.](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyIiLCIiLCJDP8KsUyrigYsiLCIiLCJbXCIwXCJdXG4wIl0=)

Comment: @emanresuA you could have at the very least mentioned what it was that isn't printable ascii.

Comment: Does this work for the empty string? (I tried inputting `"⟨  ⟩"` to the decoder which didn't work.) Also, the output seems to have a trailing space one must remove, is that the web app doing that?

Comment: @emanresuA I realise that now after I fixed my solution (obviously). I more meant at the time instead of being cryptically vague.

Comment: @JonathanAllan the empty string would be input as `[]`

Comment: @emanresuA "Input list of characters". `["|q"]` isn't a list of characters now is it. It'd need to be `["|", "q"]`, which does in fact work. It seems like you're just trying to find problems now for the sake of it :p

Comment: "if you exclude whitespace it must be excluded from both the input and the output" - this presumably excludes spaces from the input but includes them in the output

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 + 4 bytes

### [Encoder](https://tio.run/#%23y0rNyan875N0YvvD3T3//R/uaAWxug/PeLhzWsXJ6fr///9XUlDSUUqrUAIA)

```
OḅȷịØṖxɗ/
```

### [Decoder](https://tio.run/#%23y0rNyan8/98n6cT2h7t7/v//b08X8D8NAA)

```
LbȷỌ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan875N0YvvD3T3//R/uaAWxug/PeLhzWsXJ6fr/sx41zNWxftQwR0HXTgHItj7cfminIVCJtc@jhpkqxzZZK4EkC3JKixVAjNz8olSQMoQOoBLDI/uPdR3r4nq4cxXY5HCdQ0sfNa053A4kIv//V9JQ0lFKq1ACAA)

Both are monadic links. The encoder takes a pair of Jelly strings (character followed by string to encode). The decoder takes the encoded string as the first argument and ignores the second argument (but doesn’t mind if it is the excluded character). This takes inspiration from [@CommandMaster’s 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/266521/42248) so be sure to upvote that one too!

Now fixed (properly!) to handle all printable ASCII and return strings. Thanks to @JonathanAllan for his patience in highlighting problems with previous versions.

### Explanations

#### Encoder

```
O         | Codepoints of strings
 ḅȷ       | Convert both from base 1000
       ɗ/ | Reduce using the following as a dyad:
   ịØṖ    | - Index (the codepoint of the single character) into the list of printable ASCII (will always be a different character)
      x   | - Repeat this as many times as the base-1000 decoded string
```

#### Decoder

```
L    | Length
 bȷ  | Convert to base 1000
   Ọ | Convert from code points to ASCII
```

Comment: Very clever I/O hack!

Comment: ...Although it seems to break in multiple ways if the forbidden character is a space.

Comment: @UnrelatedString thanks, and good point. I’ve modified to say that I’m excluding printable whitespace, as permitted in the question

Comment: Seems your output still contains spaces, I clarified that excluding white space must apply to both the input and the output.

Comment: @mousetail fixed now by doing unary of base 1000-converted codepoints (so output will be \$a * 1000^{n-1}\$ characters where \$a\$ is the codepoint of the first character and \$n\$ is the number of characters in the input.)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Quite right. Fixed now at cost of two bytes. I like your answer better though!

Comment: Thanks for your patience @JonathanAllan. Hopefully now actually fixed.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 9 + 9 = 18 bytes

### Encoder, 9 bytes:

```
⍘⍘Ｓ⁺¶γ⁻γＳ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMpsTg1uATITEdmeuYVlJZA2Zo6CgE5pcUaSjF5SjoK6ZpAvm9mHlAgXUcBRR0QWP//75yfkqrgnp@TxpX/X7csBwA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: "Decodes" the input as base 97 and "encodes" it as base 95. (Base 97 is needed to prevent the input from having leading zeros.)

### Decoder, 9 bytes:

```
⍘⍘Ｓ⁻γＳ⁺¶γ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMpsTg1uATITEdmeuYVlJZA2Zo6Cr6ZeaXFGuk6CijimkCZgByghFJMnpKOQjpQwPr/f@8IW7eCBK0Efa78/7plOQA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: "Decodes" the input as base 95 and "encodes" it as base 97.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 68 bytes

```python
e=lambda s,c:str([*s]).replace(c,'#')
d=lambda s,c:eval(s.replace('#',c))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3PVNtcxJzk1ISFYp1kq2KS4o0orWKYzX1ilILchKTUzWSddSV1TW5UpBVpZYl5mgUw5UAFegka2pCDfQuKMrMK9FI1UhS8kjNycnXUSjPL8pJUVTSUTJU0tTkgkgnVZakFmuk4FIGUQs1EuZWAA)

Inspired by Arnauld's JS answer. The encoder converts to a stringified list of code points, replacing the excluded character with a "#". The decoder replaces "#" with the excluded character and returns a list of code points.

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 73 bytes

```python
e=lambda s,c:s.hex().replace(c,'#')
d=lambda s,c:b''.fromhex(s.replace('#',c))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3_VJtcxJzk1ISFYp1kq2K9TJSKzQ09YpSC3ISk1M1knXUldU1uVKQ1SSpq-ulFeXnglQWw1UC1ekka2pCTXUpKMrMK9FI1UhS8kjNycnXUSjPL8pJUVTSUTJU0tTkgkin4FIAUQUxC-ZSAA)

Also inspired by Arnauld's JS answer. Converts to/from hex, replacing the excluded character with a "#".

Comment: Is taking bytes as input legal here? IMO the task is about console-like input, even if you make it a function to save a few bytes (asking, 'cause I just switched to py2 to work around long `.decode()` and `.encode()` for a hex-based solution...)

Comment: @STerliakov [Our consensus for what a string is](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2214/whats-a-string/8964#8964) ([it's also stated in the default I/O methods](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25275))

Comment: This takes bytes plaintext to a string ciphertext back to a list of integers plaintext; using bytes in all cases or a list of integers in all cases would both seem reasonable, but using multiple string-like things across the answer does seem a little counter to the spirit of the question. Probably worth adding casts and asking about this in the meantime I would think.

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 61 bytes

```javascript
e=s=>c=>(s+"").split(c).join`#`
d=s=>c=>s.replace(/#/g,c).split`,`
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XdBBCsIwEAXQvaeI6WaCMd0KUkFR8AC6b0lGqYREkkj1LG660CN4GG9jbRMXbv8f3gxzfxirsG2fl3CYzt4rLHyxkMUC_IRSJvxZ1wEkEydbmzIrRyr2Xjg860oi5Fl-5DKOlryM0ktjIGhkpytSEASDDdnhNWz6zAETQwt0i1pbThrrtBpTxoByyuYjaY23GoW2R4hQl35ZhYlN6BoTOnT9tn1twmzpXHUD9RN6nP3xEWTz4fj0jg8)

(It's five bytes less than on ATO because of `e=`, newline and `d=`.). Encodes as a list of ascii codes, which normally contain only digits and commas. Then the forbidden character is replaced with `#`.

The decoder does the reverse and returns an array of strings of ascii codes, like `["72","101", ...]`. There are JS functions that interpret this as a sequence of integers (in particular `new Uint8Array`). An iterable of integers [is a string](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8964).

Answer (score 0):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 122 + 68 = 190 bytes

```
>-[-[-<]>>+<]>[->+>+>+>+<<<<]>>->>->+>+>,[-<<<-<->>>>]<<<[>>-<<[-]]<[>>-<<[-]]>>[->+<]>[<<<<++<++>>>>>-]<<<,[[-<<.>>]<.>,]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TUzLCoAwDPsVPW/1C0rO/oGH0YOPCeJQEPz@merFJpSSJpmucTvWe95rhSRCDQhcSRA@KIeiOF2INKmKUgCMZ@KHW8x@J94GL/J8CKT7IZ6IyTs6j3eIVmvucylnbIbzKkv7AA)

```
,[->+>+<<]>>[>+<[-<-<+>>]<[>>->.[-]<<<[-<+>]]>>[>+<[-]]<<<[->+<]>>,]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fJ1rXTttO28Ym1s4uGkhH69ro2mjb2cXaRNvZ6drpRevG2tiARLXtYuFKYiFiQDZQSCf2/39FKgEFRXoA@tgy7C0j1T6FgXL9oA6V0VRGriUKAA)

A Simple Unary encoder. Typically uses `!` as the unary char and space as the separator, though if either of those chars are the exclusion char, uses `#` and `"` instead. (Char codes 32, 33, 34, and 35 respectively)

### With Comments

#### Encoder

```
>-[-[-<]>>+<]>    Load 33
[->+>+>+>+<<<<]>  Smear it across 4 places
                  This is used to check the exclusion character as well as to store them
>->>->            Lower to 32
+>+>              Load two not flags
,                 Load the Exclusion Char
[-<<<-<->>>>]     Subtract any equals will be zeroed
<<<[>>-<<[-]]<[>>-<<[-]]  Invert the invert flags
>>[->+<]                  Add them essentially an or
>[<<<<++<++>>>>>-]        If either are true increment both chars by 2
<<<,
[                 Main Loop WHILE we have input
  [-              decrement the char
    <<.>>         Output the unary char
  ]
  <.>             Output the seperator
  ,               Read the next char
]
```

#### Decoder

```
,[->+>+<<] Load the first char as the unary char and spread it to the working char as well
>>[ While we have working chars
    >+< Set up the inverse flag
    [-<-<+>>]   Compare to the unary char
    <[ if theyre not equal
      >>- flip the invert flag
      >.[-] output and clear the running total
      <<<[-<+>]]
    >>[ Otherwise
      >+<
      [-]] Increment the running total
    <<<[->+<] Restore the test char
    >> Go home
,] Repeat
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 19 + 20 = 39 bytes

Encode:

```
++@0×2<@2∶♭⋯-@\0⊂@a
```

Decode:

```
↘1+@\0⍘⋯↯~7-+@0×2<@2
```

[Try them online!](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=RW5jb2RlIOKGkCArK0Aww5cyPEAy4oi24pmt4ouvLUBcMOKKgkBhCkRlY29kZSDihpAg4oaYMStAXDDijZjii6_ihq9-Ny0rQDDDlzI8QDIKCkVuY29kZSAiYWJjZGUiIEAxCkVuY29kZSAiYWJjZGUiIEAyCgpEZWNvZGUgQDEgRW5jb2RlICIxMjM0IiBAMQpEZWNvZGUgQDIgRW5jb2RlICJhYmNkZSIgQDIK)

---

To encode, we prepend "a" to the string, convert it to bitwise representation, and then:

- if the excluded letter is less than ASCII '2', we use '2' and '3' for the bits
- otherwise we use '0' and '1' for the bits

The "a" is prepended to the string because it was the most character-efficient way of ensuring that the characters are always encoded into 7 bits each, otherwise a string like "1234" would be encoded as 6-byte characters